# Draw curcuit by transfer function

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transfer-function

1. Using one operational amplifier, draw the circuit of an amplifier with the following transfer function:
   Vo = 6V1 + 3V2 + V3.
2. Using one operational amplifier, draw the circuit of an amplifier with the following transfer function:
   Vo = V1 + 2V2 − 10V

What I have tried:
[image]

Can you show the formula? Thank you

Comment: Home work? What have you been able (or not) to come up with already?

Comment: @Bart I have tried to do it. I tried with superposition and all of them have different An, so I think in non inverting shoud be one more resistor. But I don't know what to add. In the second example the same, but here we have voltage source in both sides and I can't figure out, why they have different An

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ V_o = 6V_1 + 3V_2 + V_3= 10\cdot(6V_1 + 3V_2 + V_3)/10 \$
where non-inverting gain = 9+1 and inverting gain =9

[image]

Here shown with V1,2,3 with unique values of 0.01,0.10,1.0 to show distinct gains of 6,3,1 with 1.36 V out.

You can do the 2nd one.

Comment: you can play with this http://tinyurl.com/yakjes5x

Comment: Can you share the fomula, please? How you found that non inverting gain is 9+1?

Comment: I decided that a common denominator was needed for the sum of each multiplier 6+3+1=10 but since this was not inverting it had to be in the form of 9+1.  thus 10/10 times gain.

Comment: As I understand, the second one will be like: Vo = V1 + 2V2 − 10V= (1+3-10)= -4
Inverting: 10k | Feedback: -4k | Inverting: 1k & 3k (all in Ohms). Am I right?